# After remove the component inside JPanel, nothing to show

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

Hi I have a JPanel which has many JPanel inside. When the user changed data in the inside panel. I need to refresh the outerpanel; I removed all insider panel and add the new inside panel. My problem is that  there are no inside panel showing after refresh. If I make the JFrame minimize  and then maximize, it shows the refresh panel. Would someone tell me how to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

There is my code to remove and add the new JPanel

```
private void getListCommentPane(){

      //sortPage

     Component[] components = jpListCommentPane.getComponents();
        for (Component component : components) {
            jpListCommentPane.remove(component);
            jpListCommentPane.validate();
        }

      ArrayList<CommentItem>sortComment= lstComment;
     Collections.sort(sortComment,CommentItem.sortPage);
     for(CommentItem comm: sortComment){
                    //The class DivCommentJPane extends JPanel
         DivCommentJPane d=new DivCommentJPane(comm, this);
         jpListCommentPane.add(d);

     }  

     jpListCommentPane.repaint();

 }
```

Comment: From your description, it seems that the panel isn't being revalidated automatically when new components are added to it.  Try explicitly calling [`revalidate()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#revalidate%28%29) on your parent panel after all of the inner panels are added to it.

Comment: Try calling `jpListCommentPane.revalidate()` instead of `jpListCommentPane.repaint()`, do this last, do it once.  There should be no need to call `jpListCommentPane.validate();` and especially from within a loop :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer thanks it works. How can I mark your comment as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After removing and adding your components to `jpListCommentPane`, try calling `jpListCommentPane.revalidate()` instead of `jpListCommentPane.repaint()`, do this last, do it once. There should be no need to call `jpListCommentPane.validate();` and especially from within a loop

`revalidate` will instruct the container that it needs to perform a layout and update its contact hierarchy